# Inverted string concatenation

Tags: javascript, regex, string, typescript

I'm having some problems concatenating strings in TypeScript. My code is

```
const str = 'my string';
if(regex1.match(str)) {
    const replaced = str.replace(regex1, '');
    console.log(replaced + '.ts')
}
```

The problem is in the string concatenation, Node outputs

```
.tsreplaced
```

Instead of

```
replaced.ts
```

It only happens with that string. Other string concatenations work fine.

Comment: How is `regex1` defined?

Comment: There is no match function on regex, it should be `str.match`

Comment: Or [regex.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Comment: Check if the string has a unicode [right-to-left mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark)

Comment: Node should be crashing with an error : `Uncaught TypeError: regex1.match is not a function`. If it doesn't crash and actually outputs `.tsreplaced`, then `regex1` is not a regex. You didn't provide enough code to solve your problem.

Comment: Have any of the comments, answer, or external research resolved this question?